# how to use Twitter typeahead.js with Jsrender compile function

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, template-engine, jquery-templates, jsrender

The typeahead.js docs show examples using Hogan.js, but i'm going to use Jsrender templates.Any templating engine can be used as long as it supports the expected API.
There is example using Underscore.js templates.
Here is configuration example using Underscore.js to support this by executing the following JavaScript once when the document is ready:

```
 $(function($) {    
      _.compile = function(templ) {
         var compiled = this.template(templ);
         compiled.render = function(ctx) {
            return this(ctx);
         }
         return compiled;
      }
      $('.product-typeahead').typeahead({
         header: '<h3>Products</h3>',
         template: 
       '<p><strong><%= name %></strong>:&nbsp;$<%= price %></p>',
         name: 'products',
         valueKey: 'name',
         engine: _,
         local: [
            {
               id: 0,
               name: "Deluxe Bicycle",
               price: 499.98
            },
            {
               id: 1,
               name: "Super Deluxe Trampoline",
               price: 134.99
            },
            {
               id: 2,
               name: "Super Duper Scooter",
               price: 49.95
            }
         ]
      }).on('typeahead:selected', function(event, datum) {
         $('#productID').val(datum.id);
         $('#productPrice').val("$" + datum.price);
      });
   });
```

I need to implement above typehead autocomplete using JSrender templating engine.I have tried solution provided at https://github.com/BorisMoore/jsrender/issues/30 by Author Boris Moore. How can this be achieved using jsRender?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try this - wrap `$.templates` as your engine:

```
var jsRenderEngine = {
      compile: $.templates
   };

$('.product-typeahead').typeahead({
   ...
   engine: jsRenderEngine,
   local: [
      ...
   ]
}).on('typeahead:selected', function(event, datum) {
   ...
});
```

Or alternatively extend `$.templates` to make it your engine - make it its own 'compile' method!:

```
$.templates.compile = $.templates;

$('.product-typeahead').typeahead({
   ...
   engine: $.templates,
   local: [
      ...
   ]
}).on('typeahead:selected', function(event, datum) {
   ...
});
```

Comment: @MikMark: I added an alternative approach above. Can you confirm whether it also works?

Comment: Ok - I have removed it from my answer for now. Thanks.